# @Async support not working with glassfish 3.1.2 and Spring 3.1.2

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, asynchronous, glassfish, glassfish-3

I am trying to enable `<async-supported>true</async-supported>` in web.xml for a spring application. But unable to do so. Please check the below error. Any idea how to resolve it ?

Glassfish 3.1.2

Spring 3.1.2

JDK 1.7

```
<web-app version="3.0" 
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">


<servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/app/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>        
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>        
    </servlet>
```

**Error:**

> SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;
>   lineNumber: 21; columnNumber: 82; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid
>   content was found starting with element 'mvc:async-support'. One of
>   '{"http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc":message-converters,
>   "http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc":argument-resolvers,
>   "http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc":return-value-handlers}' is
>   expected.     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5389)
>     at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:498)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:917)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:901)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:733)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2019)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1669)

UPDATE 1:

**NOT WORKING**

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>ASYNC</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
```

**JAVA MELODY WORKING FILTER WITH ASYNC SUPPORT**

```
    <filter>
        <filter-name>javamelody</filter-name>
        <filter-class>net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter</filter-class>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>javamelody</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>ASYNC</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Please share your spring config, that's where the problem is.  You can't define this in your web.xml.  It's purely a spring thing.

Comment: Essex, It's perfectly legal in web.xml. I have the configuration for javamedly monitoring with async in web.xml. Its working without any issues. But the same async tag either with filtering or servlet tags for my spring servlet not working... pls see the updated question

Comment: Its just the introduction of async-supported tag stopped everything. spring config files are valid and I have nothing changed in those files. If I remove this tag, everything is working

Answer (score -1):

The error message seems to be coming from Spring, not GlassFish.

The element '`mvc:async-support`' is on `lineNumber: 21`, `columnNumber: 82` of some file (probably your `beans.xml`? I'm not sure, I'm not a Spring expert) and it is invalid.

That particular element may not be in your version of Spring, or the XML may be malformed. The error message is giving you 3 other options to use as alternatives though.

Comment: it's not the invalid config... Because the same config works fine for the other filter...

Comment: Can you share more of the server log? The error message is telling you the config is invalid, but none of what you shared matches the configuration it's complaining about. It is **not** complaining about your web.xml. There may be a 3rd party JAR which is causing the problem, for example. More of the log will show that.